# ITMS-90289 - Using App Groups in Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, code-signing-entitlements, ios-app-group

I have tried to submit my app to the Mac App Store and I am being shown Error ITMS-90289.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Should I be naming the app group something different?

[image: ERROR ITMS-90289]

> ERROR ITMS-90289: "Invalid code signing entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X. Specifically, value '[group.co.uk.smudgeinc.BLANK]' for key 'com.apple.security.application-groups' in 'co.uk.smudgeinc.BLANK' is not supported. This value should be a string or an array of strings, each starting with your TEAMID followed by a dot '.'."

Comment: Have you tried the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680194/xcode-4-1-code-signing-issue

Comment: @BSMP I don't think this helps with this question unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should macOS App Group name start with \`group.\` or Development Team ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037745/should-macos-app-group-name-start-with-group-or-development-team-id)

Answer (score 5):

`group.identifier` is used for iOS App Group names.

For Mac projects, the App Group should start with your Team ID (found here: https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership).

When you add an App Group to your project, Xcode fills the name with `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)`.  My project failed validation when I used `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix).name`, showing a similar message to yours.

Explicitly setting this value to `[Team ID].name` resolved the issue for me (i.e. Team ID is "ABC123" – use `ABC123.name`).